# Slander and Avici Hell?

Tags: hells

I read about how instead of believing if slander is done then that person will goto Avicii Hell. I don’t see this discussed much when researching Buddhism, it seems mainly mentioned by Nichiren?

Does anyone have more information about what this means? What is everyone’s thoughts on this? Why isn’t there more information on something so big?

Answer (score 2):

For bikkhus, You can look at the vinaya, Monks’ Pācittiya 3,
https://suttacentral.net/pli-tv-pvr1.2/en/horner-brahmali

the buddha says that you go to hell when you slander the buddha or the noble ones, like here https://suttacentral.net/sn6.9/en/sujato

https://suttacentral.net/t211.30/en/beal

but for slander of a puthujjana by another puthujjana, that's seems to be the usual harsh speech, so no explicit direct destination.

Comment: `puthujjana by another puthujjana`, if speaking Dhamma? In the case a not Bhikkhu teaches Dhamma, the Bhikkhu has to pay reverance, while normaly not allowed toward householder, and younger. Maybe good if investigating such for this answer, good householder.

Answer (score 0):

Slander the Buddha, the good Dhamma, what is proper and right, and the carrier of such and their deeds, the Noble Ones, requires wrong view and such strong wrong view will definitely lead to hell. More about critic and praise in [AN 4.83: Avannaraha Sutta - Dispraise](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.083.bodh_en.html) and see also [Respect and Veneration](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,2015.msg9334.html#post_ea3)

But it does not stop here. Even if slandering a worldling, yet a giver, person of goodness, one one owes gratitude, such as father and mother, teacher, leader of ones community, recluses... also such leads to hell and if gaining a human existence he/she is not influential wherever reborn, he/she is low-born wherever reborn. [The Shorter Analysis of Action](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.than_en.html).

Note and worthy to think about is that physical action might have there effects quick but it is based on mental actions, thought, that has the most impact for a long term, and so even if not spoken out, not physical acted, just thinking "idiot" can have a lot of impact if matching the well gone and well going.

> One who tells lies (about others) goes to niraya; one who has done evil and says "I did not do it" also goes to niraya. Both of them being evil-doers, suffer alike (in niraya) in their next existence. [DHP](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.22.bpit_en.html#s-dhp-306)

Take care!

*[This is not given for trade, exchange, stacks, Buddh-ism but for release. For further questions on it or if seeking space for talking about, one may use this exit [•](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=forum)]*

Comment: thanks for your answer. Am I correct in this has to be with bad intent for it to be slander?

Comment: I mean with intent to harm/bad intentions? Is it similar to like hate?

Comment: Not-knowing, avijja, leads as well to it, good householder @jj5828 jet promted, deliberatly, not even a question.

Comment: See also http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.than_en.html even failing proper reverance.

Comment: The save bet therefore: `In five ways, young householder, should a householder minister to ascetics and brahmans as the Zenith: (i) by lovable deeds,
(ii) by lovable words,
(iii) by lovable thoughts,
(iv) by keeping open house to them,
(v) by supplying their material needs. ' [SIGALA](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara_en.html)